# React JS: Apply Material-UI CssBaseline

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I want to give my new `React` app a consistent look and feel using `Material-UI`.  Also, I want the styles and such to be easily maintainable.  So the default theme seems like a pretty good start.  The `cssBaseline` offered by `Material-UI` seems to check all the boxes, so I want to give it a try.  The thing is, surprise, it's not working.  Css themes aren't really my thing.  Am I misguided here or what?  The following code is what I've implemented in my App.js component with no luck (taken from [here](https://material-ui.com/style/css-baseline/) ).  I'm hoping is just an implmentation detail.

```
import React from "react";
import Footer from "./Footer";
import CssBaseline from "@material-ui/core/CssBaseline";
import AddTodo from "../containers/AddTodo";
import VisibleTodoList from "../containers/VisibleTodoList";

const App = () => (
  <React.Fragment>
    <CssBaseline />
    <div>
      <AddTodo />
      <VisibleTodoList />
      <Footer />
    </div>
  </React.Fragment>
);

export default App;
```

**EDIT**: This is the `index.js` located in the root of the project:

```
    import React from "react";
    import { render } from "react-dom";
    import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
    import { Provider } from "react-redux";
    import App from "./components/App";
    import rootReducer from "./reducers";

    const store = createStore(rootReducer);

   render(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
          <React.Fragment>
            <CssBaseline />
            <App />
          </React.Fragment>
        </MuiThemeProvider>
      </Provider>,
      document.getElementById("root")
    );
```

**EDIT:**  My new App.js

```
import React from "react";
import Footer from "./Footer";
import AddTodo from "../containers/AddTodo";
import AppBar from "../components/AppBar";
import VisibleTodoList from "../containers/VisibleTodoList";

const App = () => (
  <div>
    <AppBar />
    <AddTodo />
    <VisibleTodoList />
    <Footer />
  </div>
);
export default App;
```

Comment: The edits I added to my post are how I got CssBaseLine to work.  The question I have now is, how come the fonts and Material-UI components aren't respecting the CSS?

Comment: `CssBaseline` won't style components or add fonts, it is simply a css reset AFAIK (like normalize.css). https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/docs/src/pages/style/css-baseline/css-baseline.md

Comment: @DavinTryon...Yeah, that's what I was kind of thinking, thanks.  I guessing I need to something in the components using "withTheme"?   You've got an old dog trying to learn new tricks here.

Comment: I hear you :)  Check out the component demos and the `withStyles` HOC, also, you can just add roboto as a `link` to the `head`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The CSSBaseline component should be used inside a Material UI ThemeProvider component.
In your example you did not include a ThemeProvider so there is no Material UI theme.

See official documentation for how to setup ThemeProvider : https://material-ui.com/customization/themes/#muithemeprovider

Based on this sample, a minimal working example with CSSBaseline would be :

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { MuiThemeProvider, createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import CssBaseline from "@material-ui/core/CssBaseline";
import Root from './Root';

const theme = createMuiTheme();

function App() {
  return (
    <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <React.Fragment>
        <CssBaseline />
        <Root />
      </React.Fragment>
    </MuiThemeProvider>
  );
}

render(<App />, document.querySelector('#app'));
```

To get the Roboto font loaded, add this to your html template

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500">
```

For a more complete sample, look at the source code of this official sample : https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/tree/master/examples/create-react-app/src

- public/index.html : loading of roboto font
- src/withRoot.js : ThemeProvider and CSSBaseline setup
- src/pages/index.js : sample components with MUI theme applied

Comment: Okay, but I don't know where render should go.  Does it go in the index.js or what?  I've updated my question with more code.  Thanks

Comment: You'll see in my edit that I added document.querySelector("#app").  No compilation errors, but the fonts are rendered as Times Roman, so I don't think the theme is being applied.

Comment: I've got it added, but the fonts are still Times Roman and the controls don't seem to pick-up the CSS.

Comment: https://material-ui.com/style/typography/
"The Roboto font will not be automatically loaded by Material-UI"
You may use any font family you like, but if you want to use Roboto, add this to your index.html :
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500">

Comment: If you like a more complete sample look at this one : https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/tree/master/examples/create-react-app/src

Comment: I've update my answer with infos for adding roboto font, and link to complete sample