# Unable to use CssBaseline

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I tried to follow the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51658793/react-js-apply-material-ui-cssbaseline) but I get an error.

```
TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
const theme = createMuiTheme();
```

I'm trying to get `<CssBaseline />` to apply it's default styles. How can I? Here's my `App.js`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import CssBaseline from '@material-ui/core/CssBaseline';
import NavBar from './components/header/NavBar';
import {MuiThemeProvider, createMuiTheme} from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider'
import Hero from './components/hero/Hero'
import './App.css';

const theme = createMuiTheme();

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <React.Fragment>
          <CssBaseline />
          <NavBar />
          <Hero/>
        </React.Fragment>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure, but the difference in the code is the `<div>` element. Try wrapping `<NavBar />` and `<Hero/>` in a `<div>` and see if that works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`createMuiTheme` is not existing in `material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider` module

It exists in `core` module. So you should import it like this.

> `import { createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';`

refs: https://material-ui.com/customization/themes/

Comment: Thanks! Can you explain why some modules require the `@` and some don't?